# Is there an exception to the law of large numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

I was reading about the law of large numbers, and under its strong formulation it says that *the sample average converges **almost surely***. That means that it may exist a finite subset with measure $0$ whose sample average does not converge. I was wondering myself about infinite sequences with all elements $\{x_k \} \in [0, 1]$ and the average of all their terms. For me, this is a problem that can take  advantage of the law of large numbers to reach a solution. But the fact that this *almost surely* is there, makes me think about the existence of a sequence whose all-terms-average does not exist.

Do this kind of sequences exist? Could you write an example?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Let $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ be strictly increasing with $f(1)=1$ and with $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n+1)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^nf(j)=0.$ For example $f(n)=n!$.  Let  $x_k=0$ if $f(2n)\le k<f(2n+1)$ and let $x_k=1$ if $f(2n-1)\le k<f(2n).$

Comment: The law of large numbers does not imply that there "may exist a finite subset with measure 0 whose sample average does not converge".  It presupposes that there is a population expected value for the sample mean to converge to, and there are distributions where no such population expected value exists

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $100011111111100000000...$ with runs of length $1$, $3$, $9$, $27$, etc, is an example.   Each run reverses the preponderance of all previous votes, so the running average fluctuates between limits but does not converge.

Comment: This is the one that I am thinking about, but this sequence could the same as 1010101010101... with the terms reordered (I think). Once I read that we tend to see sequences as a dynamic process, but it's just a collection of numbers and that what we call the limit it's the accumulation point. Under that point of view, I don't know how to assert a limit to such proposed infinite sequence, because the  order shouldn't matter to find the accumulation point. Do I make sense myself?

Comment: The usual definition, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n$ exists, _does_ pay attention to order.  If you want a different definition and different set of consequences, go for it.  But I don't know how.  There is a thing called "Banach limits" you can google, but I don't think it will make you happy.